# Can not find cordova-3.0.0.jar after building android project

Tags: jar, cordova

I have exactly followed the instruction to build the cordova android project, and everything seems not bad without error until the last step I can not resolve the red X in Eclipse android project where the "org.apache.cordova.*" can not be import.

Did I missed anything, or how can I get the cordova.jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resolved the problem ---

Go to https://github.com/apache/cordova-android#building , and follow the instructions, you can get cordova-dev.jar file.

Comment: is this jar identical to the non-dev variant?

Comment: That didn't work for me. `ant jar` command says `BUILD FAILED
Target "jar" does not exist in the project`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

When creating the project with cordova CLI or phonegap CLI you have to import TWO generated projects into eclipse:

- YourProject
- YourProject-CordovaLib

The latter is the cordova.jar equivalent, you should not need to explicitly use the .jar library.